# ExtJS Dynamically resizing Grid column

Tags: extjs

I need to be able to dynamically change the width of a column in my grid according to the length of the data which is loaded for that column.  For example, I have a column for "Name", and the names might get really long but I want to be able to show the entire name.

Answer (score 2):

when data is loaded to your store there is fired event 'load'...

loop thru the results, find out longst name, and adjust ColumnModel...